# What are these pax tarball characteristics and comments?

Tags: linux, 7-zip, tar, archiving, posix

I created a pax archive with GNU tar 1.34 under Debian 11 and, upon viewing the tarball in 7-Zip (23.01) File Manager on Windows 10, I noticed these fields on the archived items:

| Name | Characteristics | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `9charfile` | `0 POSIX ASCII` |  |
| `long 70-character name of file` | `0 POSIX ASCII PAX pax_path pax_size` | `65-character name of directory/PaxHeaders/long 70-character name` |
| `longer 96-character name of file` | `0 POSIX ASCII PAX pax_path pax_size` | `65-character name of directory/PaxHeaders/longer 96-character nam` |

Here is a `tar -tf` of my tarball:

```
65-character name of directory/
65-character name of directory/9charfile
65-character name of directory/long 70-character name of file
65-character name of directory/longer 96-character name of file
```

If you take note of the **Comment** field, the parent directory+`PaxHeaders`+filename uses a cutoff filename (entire field is 100 characters). The file with the shortest filename, only nine characters in length, not only has no comment whatsoever but is also missing `PAX pax_path pax_size` from the **Characteristics** field.

I created that tarball using this coincidentally very long command (with help from [this guide](https://reproducible-builds.org/docs/archives/)):

```
find '65-character name of directory' -print0 | LC_ALL=C sort -z | tar -cv --totals --posix --full-time --mode='a=r,u+w,a+X' --owner=0 --group=0 --numeric-owner --mtime='@0' --pax-option='exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders/%f,delete=atime,delete=ctime' --no-acls --no-selinux --no-xattrs -C /parent_dir --no-recursion --null -T - -f out.tar
```

Furthermore, I created a second tarball as a Unicode test:

```
$ tar -tf unicodetest.tar
Random webpage I saved (低配版)_files/
Random webpage I saved (低配版)_files/sample-picture.jpg
Random webpage I saved (低配版)_files/sample-script.js
Random webpage I saved (低配版).htm
ascii-labelled file.bin
```

Viewed in 7-Zip (tar root):

| Name | Characteristics | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `Random webpage I saved (低配版)_files` | `5 POSIX UTF8 MaxUnicode=37197 PAX pax_path` | `./PaxHeaders/Random webpage I saved (ä½Žé…ç)_files` |
| `Random webpage I saved (低配版).htm` | `0 POSIX UTF8 MaxUnicode=37197 PAX pax_path` | `./PaxHeaders/Random webpage I saved (ä½Žé…ç).htm` |
| `ascii-labelled file.bin` | `0 POSIX ASCII` |  |

Viewed in 7-Zip (`Random webpage I saved (低配版)_files` directory):

| Name | Characteristics | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `sample-picture.jpg` | `0 POSIX UTF8 MaxUnicode=37197 PAX pax_path` | `Random webpage I saved (ä½Žé…ç)_files/PaxHeaders/sample-picture.jpg` |
| `sample-script.js` | `0 POSIX UTF8 MaxUnicode=37197 PAX pax_path` | `Random webpage I saved (ä½Žé…ç)_files/PaxHeaders/sample-script.js` |

Notice the [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in the **Comment** fields? Is this anything of concern or simply cosmetic when viewed through 7-Zip? I find it strange that the name in the **Name** field displays Unicode correctly, but not this other field.

I'm curious:

- why the longer paths/filenames result in additional metadata
- what the purpose of each **Characteristics** and **Comment** value is
- why the **Comment** appears to cap at 100 characters
- if there are any caveats/oversights/causes for concern (as this procedure will be replicated in many tarballs to come)

My goal is to create a reproducible and portable tarball as variable-neutral as possible (filename, file length, path and contents are essentially all I need to retain). Thank you.